# C++ CLI How to read data from a table in Access database?

Tags: ms-access, c++-cli

For example, if I have an Access Database Data.accdb with 2 tables inside: Table1 and Table2, how can I read data from Table1? I know how to open the Sql connection though.

```
#using <system.data.dll>

using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;
using namespace System::Data::OleDb;

SqlConnection ^connection = gcnew SqlConnection(L"server=local;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=Data;");
connection->Open();
```

But beyond that, I don't know what to do next. How to open Table1 and read data from it, like read ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OleDb to manipulate an Access database.

```
#include <msclr\auto_handle.h>

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Data::OleDb;

    OleDbConnection connection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\MyDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
    connection.Open();

    // Reading all records
    {
        msclr::auto_handle<OleDbCommand> command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command->CommandText = "select * from Table1";
        msclr::auto_handle<OleDbDataReader> reader = command->ExecuteReader();

        while (reader->Read())
        {
            Console::WriteLine(
                "ID={0}, DESCRIPTION={1}",
                reader.get()["ID"],
                reader.get()["DESCRIPTION"]);
        }
    }

    // Insert new record
    {
        msclr::auto_handle<OleDbCommand> command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command->CommandText = "insert into Table1 (ID, DESCRIPTION) values (3, 'THREE')";
        command->ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Changing the DESCRIPTION field for all records
    {
        msclr::auto_handle<OleDbCommand> selectCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        selectCommand->CommandText = "select * from Table1";
        msclr::auto_handle<OleDbDataReader> reader = selectCommand->ExecuteReader();

        while (reader->Read())
        {
            auto newDescription = reader.get()["DESCRIPTION"]->ToString();
            newDescription += " - UPDATED!";

            msclr::auto_handle<OleDbCommand> updateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            updateCommand->CommandText =  "update Table1 set DESCRIPTION=? where ID=?";
            updateCommand->Parameters->AddWithValue("DESCRITPION", newDescription);
            updateCommand->Parameters->AddWithValue("ID", reader.get()["ID"]);
            updateCommand->ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks alot :) Can you also show me how to change value of records, for example changing Field Description of each records?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm just curious, is there a method without using msclr/auto_handle?

Comment: Sure. You can use "raw" references (ex.:OleDbCommand^, or the auto keyword). msclr::auto_handle is just a convenient way to use stack semantics when you get a reference to a disposable object back from a function call. msclr::auto_handle will automatically dispose the object upon leaving its scope, which covers the case when an exception is raised. If you don't want to use it, remember to call delete on the disposable object.